# Twisted RPC message aggregation

Tags: python, twisted, rpc

I'm working with a python application that makes remote procedure calls, using Twisted Perspective broker's callRemote, on a TCP connection. From a system call trace, it appears that multiple remote procedure calls from the sender could be aggregated together into a single sendto() call on the socket. The same behavior was observed with the receiver's response as well. I would've thought that as long as the socket was write-able and if there was some data to send, Perspective broker would send it out on the socket. But it does not appear to be the case.

1. Does Twisted's Perspective broker aggregate multiple RPC messages together for a specific reason, before they are sent on the socket ? In other words, does Twisted do something similar to Nagle's algorithm in TCP ?
2. If the above is true, is there an option to turn off this behavior ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "RPCs" or "batch".  The answer is complicated and might be "yes" or "no" depending on the particulars of what you're doing.  Are you talking about AMP or XML-RPC or REST-ish "RPC" or JSON-RPC or SOAP or Perspective Broker or Sun RPC?  Why are you expecting `sendto()` rather than `send()`?  Please attach a minimal piece of sample code.

Comment: I have now edited the question with the specific details. A system call trace shows sendto() in its listing.

Comment: There still isn't any code attached here.

Comment: It is very difficult to abstract the code out of the application and post a snippet here.

Comment: That is often the case. But without abstracting and simplifying, we will never know if it is some peculiar quirk of your highly complex quirk of your application or some fundamental behavior in Twisted.

Comment: (See http://sscce.org for a good rationale as to how to simplify and abstract for forums like Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted performs write buffering in the underlying [`twisted.internet.abstract.FileDescriptor`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-9.0.0/twisted/internet/abstract.py) object.  You can try changing the `twisted.internet.abstract.FileDescriptor.SEND_LIMIT` attribute to something smaller to force it to write to the socket more frequently.

See the [Twisted bug 4089](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4089) for discussion about the `SEND_LIMIT` and `bufferSize` attributes.

Comment: Based on the system call trace analysis, it appears that between the time the socket was found to be write-able (though epoll_wait) and the time the event loop gets to that specific socket, we might have additional messages queued on the FileDescriptor buffer. So when send() is actually invoked on the socket, multiple application messages are sent together. Thanks for pointers.